# Would reading a file sequentially result in random disk seeks?

Tags: file, filesystems, disk, sequential

I was under the impression that sequential scan of a file would actually be a sequential seek on disk. However, I read recently that the blocks of a file might not be written contiguously on disk by a file system. If inodes are used as a map and each block is obtained by following the block pointer, I am wondering whether the actual mechanism with which a file system retrieves the blocks of a file is actually sequential?

If the answer is file system dependant, it would be great to cite some major filesystems.
Thanks.

Comment: First you need to give the definition of "sequential" -- on the HDD there is no sequence, as the HDD is 3-dimentional (plate / track / sector).

Comment: @EugeneMayevski'EldoS sequential == contiguous blocks on the HDD.

Comment: @itisravi your comment unfortunately is not applicable, cause "sequential" and "contiguous" are synonims, and the problem with them has been specified in my previous comment. Moreover, two adjacent sectors are not contiguous. Sectors on the HDD from the very beginning are not numbered sequentially, so logical sector 1 and logical sector 2, even when they are on the same track (cylinder), are not neighbors.

Comment: @EugeneMayevski'EldoS Ok, did not know that. So what does contiguous allocation mean? There has to be some logic which allocates blocks to be in close physical proximity (even though not sequentially numbered) so that seek time across sectors of the same platter and across platters is minimised while reading a file.

Answer (score 0):

Filesystems *try* to allocate as much sequential blocks as possible during writes. But as they age (i.e lot of creates + deletes over time), [fragmentation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_system_fragmentation) becomes inevitable. There are heuristics to reduce fragmentation like speculative preallocation, delayed preallocation etc. Applications themselves can do things like  preallocation (example fallocate), enabling readahead and running de-fragmentation tools depending on the features available in the filesystem to make the blocks contiguous or at least reads faster.